# Displaying a 'hidden' form when text input is entered and hide it text input is empty

Tags: javascript, forms

My second form shows as soon as I type something in the input field, but I am not sure how to hide the second form if I remove the text from the input field. Any help is appreciated.

I have this code:

```js
<input style="margin-right: 5px;" type="text6" name="outstanding1" id="outstanding"
onClick="document.getElementById('form2').style.display='';" />

<script>
  var outstanding = document.getElementById("outstanding");

  outstanding.onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none";
  };
</script>
```

Comment: `outstanding.onsubmit = ...` makes little sense here - input fields do not fire a `submit` event, only forms do.

Comment: You should add an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/input_event) event handler to the input field, and then you check if its current value is empty or not - and based on that, you either hide the second form, or show it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with jquery? The posted snippet doesn't use jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input `outstanding1` is near the form that needs to show/hide you can use the [Next-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) or (as in the example) the [Subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator). The input `outstanding1` need the attribute `required` to validate/invalidate the form `form01`.

```css
form[name="form01"]:invalid ~ form[name="form02"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>outstanding: <input type="text" name="outstanding1" required></label>
</form>
<form name="form02">
  <label>Test: <input type="text" name="test"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
<script>
    var outstanding = document.getElementById("outstanding");

    outstanding.onchange = function() {
        if(outstanding.value ==='') document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none";

    };
</script>
```

or maybe you can handle input changing by `onkeydown` function